# Creating a background sprite node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an endless scroller game and I'm trying to create two backgrounds.

I have a background class like so,

```
class BackgroundMG1: SKNode {
    let background: SKSpriteNode
    let size: CGSize

    init(size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
        let hue = CGFloat((arc4random() % 1000) / 1000)
        let randomColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.background = SKSpriteNode(color: randomColor, size: size)

        super.init()

        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        background.position.x = 0
        background.position.y = 0
        addChild(background)
    }
}
```

I'm going to be populating my background with other objects so I needed it to be a class and not just a static image.

I have my game scene like so,

```
class AntarcticaMiniGame1: SKScene {

    var player: SKSpriteNode!
    var backgrounds: [BackgroundMG1]!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){

        // Initializers
        player = Player()

        // Positions
        player.position.x = 0
        player.position.y = 0
        player.zPosition = 1

        // Set up backgrounds
        backgrounds = [BackgroundMG1]()
        for i in 0..<2 {
            let background = BackgroundMG1(size: size)
            background.position.x = CGFloat(i) * size.width
            background.position.y = 0
            backgrounds.append(background)
            addChild(background)
        }

        // Add to scene
        addChild(player)

    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        player.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 25, dy:0))
    }
}
```

You can also assume that I have a ground and camera object set up. I had to omit that code because it's not relevant to this question. The player stays on the ground and the camera follows the player.

Right now, when I load the game, the player object is moving to the right as expected. I see one background, but the second one doesn't show up.

I feel like I'm making some mistakes with the positioning. I'm not a 100% how the coordinate system works in Swift.

Edit: My scene is connected to a .sks file which is totally empty right now. The game is in landscape orientation.

Comment: so you are applying a force on each frame?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I have since changed that to velocity, but that is irrelevant to the question I'm asking.

Comment: That may not b irrelevant! You may just get out of the two sprites quite fast... Forget changing such at every frame, just add some velocity at start... Also change `CGFloat((arc4random() % 1000) / 1000)` that always evaluate to 0 to `CGFloat(arc4random() % 1000) / 1000` or alike